How do I multiply a Bell state with a measurement operator?
A textbook that I am currently reading says the following: Alice and Bob share an entangled pair of qubits in the Bell state $(|00\rangle+|11\rangle)/\sqrt{2}$ . Alice performs a two outcome measurement described by measurement operators M1 and M2:
$$M_1=\begin{bmatrix}
cos(\theta) & 0 \\
0 & sin(\theta) 
\end{bmatrix}, \hspace{10px} M_2=\begin{bmatrix}
sin(\theta) & 0 \\
0 & cos(\theta) 
\end{bmatrix}.$$
After the measurement the state is either $cos(\theta)|00\rangle+sin(\theta)|11\rangle$  or $sin(\theta)|00\rangle+cos(\theta)|11\rangle$, depending on the measurement outcome, 1 or 2.
I am trying to understand how the authors arrive at this calculation. So far, I have not made progress except for,
$$(|00\rangle+|11\rangle)/\sqrt{2} = 1/\sqrt{2}\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
0 \\
0\\
0
\end{pmatrix}+1/\sqrt{2}\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
0 \\
0\\
1
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
1/\sqrt{2} \\
0 \\
0\\
1/\sqrt{2}
\end{pmatrix}$$.
I am not sure how to multiply this vector by a $2\times2$ matrix like $M_1$ or $M_2$.

The Bell state is shared by two parties: Alice and Bob. The measurement is performed just by Alice. So you need to know how to convert something that just Alice does into something both Alice and Bob do. But Bob does nothing in this circumstance, which is represented by the $2\times 2$ identity matrix. Thus, you should really consider the measurement operators
$$
M_1\otimes I=\text{diag}(\cos\theta,\cos\theta,\sin\theta,\sin\theta),\qquad M_2\otimes I=\text{diag}(\sin\theta,\sin\theta,\cos\theta,\cos\theta).
$$
Now if you calculate things like
$$
(M_1\otimes I)(|00\rangle+|11\rangle)/\sqrt{2},
$$
you'll find one of the claimed outputs up to normalisation, and the normalisation tells you with what probability you get that measurement result ($1/2$).
